# FourierTransform of a simple two-dimensional function

Tags: fourier-analysis

`FourierTransform` correctly computes the transform of a one-dimensional "box" function, or `HeavisidePi[x]`:

```
FourierTransform[HeavisidePi[x1], x1, s1]
```

(* $sinc(\pi\ s1)$ *)

The `HeavisidePi[x1,x2]` function in two (or more) spatial dimensions is simply the product `HeavisidePi[x1] HeavisidePi[x2]`, and hence its Fourier transform is merely the product of the individual transforms:

(* $sinc(\pi\ s1)\ sinc(\pi\ s2)$ *)

Why won't the direct application

```
FourierTransform[HeavisidePi[x1, x2], {x1, x2}, {s1, s2}]
```

Give this (relatively simple) answer.

Is there any Option or other trick to getting *Mathematica* to perform this two-dimensional Fourier transform without us factoring the function "by hand" first?

Comment: It is the convolution of the Fourier transforms of each function not the product.  Reference: [Convolution_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem)

Comment: @Nasser.  Nope.  You're thinking of the product of two functions in a *single* dimension.  These are in orthogonal dimensions (x1 and x2).

Comment: Ok, I see now, yes, I was thinking of 1 D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[w_] := FourierTransform[UnitBox[x], x, w, 
   FourierParameters -> {1, -1}] /. Sin[x_] :> x Sinc[x]

Plot[Evaluate@f[ω]
 , {ω, -6 π, 6 π}
 , PlotRange -> All
 , AxesLabel -> {"ω", TraditionalForm@f[w]}
 , Exclusions -> None
 ]
```

[image]

---

```
f[w1_, w2_] := 
 FourierTransform[UnitBox[x, y], {x, y}, {w1, w2}, 
   FourierParameters -> {1, -1}] /. Sin[x_] :> x Sinc[x]

Plot3D[
 Evaluate@f[ω1, ω2]
 , {ω1, -4 π, 4 π}, {ω2, -4 π, 4 π}
 , PlotRange -> All
 , AxesLabel -> {ω1, ω2, f[ω1, ω2]}
 , Exclusions -> None
 ]
```

[image]

---

The same can be accomplished using `FunctionExpand` with the `HeavisidePi` as well.

```
FourierTransform[
  FunctionExpand[HeavisidePi[x, y]], {x, y}, {ω1, ω2}
  , FourierParameters -> {1, -1}
  ] /. Sin[x_] :> x Sinc[x]
```

---

Comment: Thanks ($+1$) that "works" (sort of).  The question becomes, then, why the 2D Fourier transform works on UnitBox[x1,x2] but not HeavisidePi[x1,x2]?  Aren't they (essentially) the same?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ahhh... yes, `FunctionExpand`.  Thanks very much.  ($\checkmark$). I'm not quite sure why you need to perform the substitution Sin[x_] :> x Sinc[x].  Aesthetics?

Comment: Just to write it in terms of `Sinc` to match the OP. No special reason.

Comment: `HeavisidePi[x,y]` is a distribution and `UnitBox[x, y]` is a usual function. The Fourier transforms of these are defined in different ways.